# formatting output data to an excel file

Tags: perl, loops, data-structures, escaping, output

This program gets numeric values from the web for each of the values in my @values array
I want these values to be printed out in a table which looks like

```
       il9  il8 il7
 2012  v1    b1
 2011  v2    b2
 2010  v3    b3
   .
   .
 2000  v12   b12
```

where v1 .. v12 are values for the first variable in @values etc. here is my program please help me structure it. Is there an escape character that could take me back to the first line of the program in perl
thanks

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl -w
  use strict;
  use LWP::UserAgent;
  use URI;
  my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;
  $browser->timeout(10);
  $browser->env_proxy;

  open(OUT, ">out");
  my $i = 2013;
  while ($i-- > 2000){print OUT "$i\n"}
  my $a = 2013 ;
  my $base = 'http://webtools.mf.uni-lj.si/public/summarisenumbers.php';
  my @values = ('il9', 'il8', 'il6' );
  foreach my $value (@values) {
print OUT "$value \n"
    while ($a-- > 2000){
                my $b = $a + 1;
                my $c = $b + 1; 
                my $query = '?query=('.$value.')'.$a.'[dp] NOT           '.$b.'[dp] NOT '.$c.'[dp]';
                my $add = $base.$query;
                #my $url = URI->new($add);  
                #my $response = $browser->get($url); 
                #if($response->is_success) {print OUT $response->decoded_content;}
                #else {die $response->status_line};
                print OUT "$query\n";
                } $a = 2013; print OUT
                        }

   close(OUT);
```

Comment: do you want to create an xls Excel file? or print tabular data to a file?

Comment: I wanted to create an excel XLSX file, anyways I figured it out thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay more attention to formatting/indentation and variable naming - it will help you a lot.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $base_url  = 'http://webtools.mf.uni-lj.si/public/summarisenumbers.php';
my @values    = ( 'il9', 'il8', 'il6' );
my $stat_data = {};

my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$browser->timeout(10);
$browser->env_proxy;

for my $value ( @values ) {

    for my $year ( 2010 .. 2013 ) {

        my $query = '?query=(' . $value . ')' . $year .'[dp] NOT           ' . ($year+1) . '[dp] NOT ' . ($year+2) .'[dp]';
        my $url   = "$base_url$query";

        my $response = $browser->get( $url );

        if( $response->is_success ) {
            ## store the fetched content in a hash structure
            $stat_data->{$year}->{$value} = $response->decoded_content;
        }
        else {
            die $response->status_line;
        }
    }
}

## print the header
print "\t", join( "\t", @values ), "\n";

## print the data by the years in reverse order
for my $year ( reverse sort keys %{$stat_data} ) {

    print $year;

    for my $value ( @values ) {
        print "\t", $stat_data->{$year}->{$value};
    }

    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry. I am working on my indentation I figured out an easier way to do this using excel writer module .

Comment: Ah, so you wanted to produce an xls file after all, not just an excel-like tab-separated text. All right then. Nevertheless I still suggest fetching the data and storing it in some structure first and produce the output in a separate step.